# Checking if an integer argument is defined for a method

Tags: java, calendar

**Scenario**: I am currently attempting to make a calendar in Java, one of the methods I have created (**getMonthSize**) is to get the size of a month (as shown). My goal currently is to make the method respond regardless of whether the argument is defined by the user (give the current month size if argument left blank, and give the size of the inputted month if argument is defined).

**Efforts**: I have given quite a thorough search for an answer on the web, I have come across answers testing to see if the arg.length==0 (although it turns out that works only if the arg is a String), and answers using something along the lines of "arg!==undefined" (which I think may be for javascript), with no avail. I have also learned that if an integer is not initialized, its default value will be 0, so that is what I tried to take advantage of with my code shown, although it seemed that java still expects me to input "0" for the method to work.

**Question**: I am hoping there is some command that checks if the argument is left blank, allowing me to set 2 cases, and achieve what I want with the method.

```
package model;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class myCalendar {
   private Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
   private int day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
   private int date=this.calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
   private int month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
   private int year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   
   public void setCalendar(int Year, int Month, int Date){
       this.calendar.set(Year,Month-1,Date);
   }
   
   public int getDay(){
      return day;
   }
   
   public int getDate () {
       return date;
   }
   
   public int getMonth(){
       return month;
   }
   
   public int getYear() {
       return year;
   }
   
   public int getFirstDay () {
       Calendar test = this.calendar;
       test.set(year, month-1, 1);
       return test.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1;
   }
   
   public int getMonthSize (int num) {
       int Month=0;
       int days=0;
       if (num>0){
       Month=num;
       } else {
       Month=month;
       }
       if(Month==1||Month==3||Month==5||Month==7  
       ||Month==8||Month==10||Month==12){   
        days=31;   
      }   
        if(Month==4||Month==6||Month==9||Month==11)   
      {   
        days=30;   
      }   
      if(Month==2)   
      {   
        if(((year%4==0)&&(year%100!=0))||(year%400==0))   
        {   
          days=29;   
        }   
        else   
        {   
          days=28;   
        }   
      }
      return days;
   }
   
   public String getNow () {
       String monthNames[]={"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
           String a=monthNames[month-1]+", "+String.valueOf(year);
       return a;
   }
   
}
```

Comment: **Stop using `java.util`** for any date or time operations, that API is outdated. Use `java.time` instead.

Comment: An `int` is never blank, because it occupies exactly 4 bytes, which is the precise amount of memory required for all its possible values.  You could use a variable of type `Integer`, which like all reference variables is permitted to be null.  It might be even better to use the `Optional` generic class, which makes concerns about missing values even clearer.

Comment: So you have a method declared as `getMonthSize(int num)` and want to call it without any parameters, like `getMonthSize()`, am I right? You just can't do that. If a method requires a parameter then you have to provide it. What you could do is to overload the method with a parameterless variant.

Comment: OK thank you all very much for your advice, this is for a school project and I am not experienced by any means. I have already designed the entire calendar using java.util.Calendar, I will give java.time a look. Am I right in guessing that polymorphism will do the trick?

Comment: What I was refering to isn't polymorphism. Simply add another parameterless  method `getMonthSize()` to your current class and make it return the default value.

Comment: @Amongalen, actually, method overloading is sometimes called "static polymorphism" or "compile time polymorphism".  It's not very useful terminology, sure, but it's sometimes used.

Comment: OK, a quick search revealed that my definition of Polymorphism was wrong. That was a relatively simple solution, cheers!

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Interesting, never encountered such terms. Good to know.

Comment: As @deHaar said, don’t use `Calendar`. Use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And use `Month.getDisplayName()` for month names, don’t hardcode those yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I understood your problem correctly.

Your problem is that your user can start the method without a valid argument. If you have a frontend than you should catch it there too. But in the backend (java) you can work with a try-block or simply with if-else.

Cast the Integer to a String and then use regex (maybe something like this

```
String text = num + "";
if (text != null && text.matches("\\d+")) {
    //...
}
```

Or you can cast your Integer to a String and use String.isEmpty().isEmpty returns true if, and only if, length() is 0. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()).

```
Sting temp = num + "";
if (num.isEmpty()) {
    //...
}
```

Or simply a try-catch Block where you cast your input to a new variable.

```
try {
    Month = Integer.parseInt(num);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // handle error
}
```

And please notice that your variable "Month" should be "month". In most programming communities everyone uses lowercase variables.

There are countless options how you can handle this situation and you can try every one of them. I hope that the ones I listed are all correct.

Edit:
Oh and I checked the other comments and I noticed that you are a beginner. Here are maybe some useful tips, so everyone in your class including the teacher can read easier your code. In most programming languages there is something like "checkstyle". It is hard to explain, but with some google you can find useful tips.

I will make a few "suggestions" to your code, which you can adopt or ignore. Like spaces between some characters some comments, etc.
But don't focus to hard on the quality. In some IDEs you can automatically format your code to "the standard". With Intellij it is. ctrl+alt+l

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class myCalendar {
    private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    private int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    private int date = this.calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    private int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    private int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    /**
     * Description what the method does.
     *
     * @param Year  what does the parameter?
     * @param Month ""
     * @param Date  ""
     */
    public void setCalendar(int Year, int Month, int Date) {
        this.calendar.set(Year, Month - 1, Date);
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public int getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    /**
     * Description what the method does.
     *
     * @return value (short description)
     */
    public int getFirstDay() {
        Calendar test = this.calendar;
        test.set(year, month - 1, 1);
        return test.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
    }

    /**
     * Description what the method does.
     *
     * @param num (short description)
     * @return (short description)
     */
    public int getMonthSize(int num) {
        int month;
        int days = 0; //My IDE tells me that need to be initialized, but why? Are there cases where the method returns 0?
        //I think that num=100 returns 0, so maybe you can catch this case with if(num > 12) or something similar
        if (num > 0) {
            month = num;
        } else {
            month = this.month;
        }
        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7
            || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {
            days = 31;
        }
        if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
            days = 30;
        }
        if (month == 2) {
            if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
                days = 29;
            } else {
                days = 28;
            }
        }
        return days;
    }

    public String getNow() {
        String monthNames[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
        String a = monthNames[month - 1] + ", " + String.valueOf(year);
        return a;
    }

}
```